# How to calculate how much items fit inside a box?

Tags: volume

This is a simple question but I just want to make sure.

I am creating a SQL program where I am trying to calculate how many cartons go on a pallet for Shipping Routing purposes.

A pallet is made up of cartons and cartons are made of items.
I have the dimensions of a carton something like 10" * 5" * 5" which gives a volume of 250.

Then lets say I have an item that has dimensions of 10" * 5" * 1" (like a bookbag) with a volume of 50 and an items that is like 4" * 3" * 2" (small box) with a volume of 24.

Is the calculation just a simple volume of the box divided by volume of the item? So we can fit 5 bookbags in that carton or about 10 small boxes in the same carton.

Is there like a complex formula for this stuff that is better suited?

Comment: Dividing the volume of the box by the volume of the item gives an *upper limit* on the amount of items you could fit in the box; it could very possibly be less, though (imagine a long rectangular box and a cubical item of the same volume - no way you're going to fit the one in the other).

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the volumes would work for cartons made of… fluid.

For the solid ones, count how many will fit in width, height and depth, and take the product of these numbers.

But that's not all. Because you can probably pack the boxes in different orientations (though maybe some must remain vertical, and maybe some are symmetrical), so you should try the different combinations (up to six of them). And after you have packed, there can remain voids on a side that you could fill with boxes in another orientation. Same holds after the last layer: there can remain a void above. (You should fill the voids to limit the possible sliding of the boxes.)

This is *not* a simple question.

[image]